How does aidl work? Don't you need a Service Manager
I read from the official Android documentation that AIDL works as follows: AIDL uses the binder kernel driver to make calls,link below
https://source.android.com/docs/core/architecture/aidl
According to the documentation, does this mean that AIDL can communicate directly with Binder drivers without registering services with the Service Manager?
Why does AIDL not need to go through the Service Manager?
